# unsigned type of an integer constant

Tags: c

I got confused of the type of an integer constant, as described [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5):

On the first row, if a constant ended without `'u'`, why decimal constant must be `signed` type, while octal or hexadecimal constant can be an `unsigned` type?

I think that taking the constant as an unsigned version if the `signed` version do not fit has problem, for example:

```
long long l1 = 0xffffffff + 0xffffffff;  // 0xffffffff is unsigned int
long long l2 = 4294967295 + 4294967295;  // 4294967295 is signed long
```

l1 is fffffffe, while l2 is 1fffffffe. and obviously l1 is wrong

Comment: It's just the rule, that's all. Probably seemed like a good idea at the time. Get used to it.

Comment: Hexadecimal values are seldom used for general (signed) arithmetic, they are mostly used for bit manipulation. Therefore it makes sense to keep constants unsigned if the "sign bit" is set.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That said, some folk are starting to use hexadecimal notation with binary floating point.

Comment: @Bathsheba Particularly [CS:APP](https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/) where there's a whole section on bit-level manipulation of FP numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to say, I'd answer with that **hexadecimal and octal numbers represent bit pattern more closely** than decimal ones, and therefore the C standard committee has decided that hex and oct numbers may be unsigned even without `U` suffix.

Think about how many people would write code like this:

```c
uint32_t b = a & 0xFFFFFFF0;

uint32_t b = a & 4294967280; // or -15?
```

Comment: You can add binary to that list to in C++. I'd expect C to follow suit, particularly with compilers that already have this as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

The issue causes problems more because of using wrong type  for the operations than the constants not being the right type.

```
// some_wide_type = some_narrow_type + some_narrow_type --> trouble
long long l1 = 0xffffffff + 0xffffffff;
long long l2 = 4294967295 + 4294967295;
```

Instead do the math using the target type

```
long long l1 = 0LL + 0xffffffff + 0xffffffff;
long long l2 = 0LL + 4294967295 + 4294967295;
```

or use 1 type (`long long`) rather than the 3 (`long long, unsigned long, long`)

```
long long l1 = 0xffffffffLL + 0xffffffffLL;
long long l2 = 4294967295LL + 4294967295LL;
```